# How do I add a Google Maps API on my Android Studio project with a coordinates searching feature?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I am trying to make an android studio project where i could implement google maps API and have a search bar where a user enters latitudes and longitudes and find the location. I tried to add google maps with a search bar, the map shows up but the app either crashes or goes back to the page previous to the maps when i try to search for any location. I am new to programming in general and this is my first android app so i do not have much idea, i tried this code with reference to multiple YouTube tutorials.

```
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap map;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    SearchView searchView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemaps);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;
                if(location!= null || !location.equals("")){
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(map.this);
                    try {
                        addressList=geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng =new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

Comment: hi, this question isn't really a good fit for SO. we're here to resolve specific technical issues which you can't resolve on your own. please go try this on your own and, if you encounter a problem, come back and post it as a new question with a full stack trace

Comment: I tried adding google maps with a search bar, the map loads too but when i enter any location the app either crashes or returns back to the previous page.